# How do I assign variable names which were used as arguments?

Tags: python, variables

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I need to assign k to the variable L. However whenever I do it just shows up as the initial L. The rest of the function works correctly. I tested so by printing k.

```
def string_avg_update(L):
    '''(list of str) -> NoneType
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' update  the given 
    list of strs to be a list of floats where each item 
    is the average of the corresponding numbers in the 
    string. Note this function does NOT RETURN the list.
    >>> L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
    >>> string_avg_update(L)
    >>> L 
    [74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
    '''

    y = L
    b = string_avg(y)
    k = []
    for item in b:
        k.append(item[1])

    L = k
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Where does it show up "as the initial L"? In this function or in the calling function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Show us your print output, and tell us what you were expecting instead. You shouldn't expect for the caller to see the effects of assignment, Python doesn't support pass-by-reference semantics