# NoneType after List Error

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble understanding the error raised from the second function. As I was hacking through the second function I realized print(x) gives me:
    [['Anna', 74.0], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]]
    None

Due to this none, I am unable to iterate through the list to and set it to L. What is causing this none? Here is a paste bin of the 3 other functions. [code here!](https://pastebin.com/RZTUiwSq). Any advice or push in the correct direction is greatly appreciated.

---

```
def string_avg(L):
'''(list of str) -> list of list
Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' return a new list of 
lists where each inner list has the format :
[name (str), average grade (float)]
Requirement: This function should be 1 line long.

>>> string_avg(['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 
98'])
[['Anna', 74.0], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]]
'''
return(average_grade((string_list(L))))


def string_avg_update(L):
'''(list of str) -> NoneType
Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' update  the given 
list of strs to be a list of floats where each item 
is the average of the corresponding numbers in the 
string. Note this function does NOT RETURN the list.
>>> L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
>>> string_avg_update(L)
>>> L 
[74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
'''

x = string_avg(L)
```

My intended code for the last function is:

```
Say I changed the last function code to: 
x = string_avg(L)       

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    L[i] = x[i][1]
```

But it says I cannot find len of nonetype, why is my x a none type?

Comment: Had you run the doctests you wrote into the docs? What was the result?

Comment: The `x = string_avg(L)` sets a local variable `x` which is lost unused when the function ends.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I got ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'] returned back to me for the second function (which is the same as the input) and the expected results for all other functions. My goal is figure out what causes the none and then set L[every index] = x[each index][1].

Comment: Ill edit the code I intend to put in the main post.

Comment: This is a follow-on question from https://stackoverflow.com/q/46599506/4014959 And I guess a few people are working on this assignment. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46637076/4014959

Answer (score 0):

`average_grade()` doesn't return a list but only prints it and returns `None`

Comment: That was exactly the issue. It slipped right by me. Thank you so much!